# Proving or disproving an inequality regarding non-negative real numbers.

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are $n$ non-negative real numbers such that
$$ n\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_j)^p\right)^{q/p}<1,$$
for some $p>1,q>1$ with $1/p+1/q=1.$
Does this imply
 $$ n a_j<1~~\text{for each}~~ j=1,2,\ldots,n. $$ 
I tried as following:
\begin{align}
\text{Since}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (a_j)^{q}\leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_j)^p\right)^{q/p} ~~~~\text{this implies}~ ~~~n(a_j)^{q}\leq n\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_j)^p\right)^{q/p}<1.
\end{align}
So, I got $n(a_j)^q<1.$ I am stuck here. Kindly help in proving this inequality, if implication is not correct then please provide a counter example.

Comment: Try $n=p=q=2$, $a_1=1/\sqrt{3}$, $a_2=1/3$.

Comment: @Kelenner Thanks for the counterexample.

Comment: You are welcome.